# Reducer updates state object which it should not be able to access

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, redux-thunk

The problem is that when on of my reducer updates its own state, it also updates the state of another reducer.

//authActions.js

```
export const authActions = {
    login: (props) => dispatch => {
        // This will make sure the loading spinner will appear.
        dispatch({
            type: POST_LOGIN_PENDING,
            payload: null
        })
        // make request to login user      
        axios.post(LOGIN_ENDPOINT, {
            email: props.email, 
            password: props.password
        }).then(res => dispatch({
            type: POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED,
            payload: res.data
        })
        ).catch( () => dispatch({
            type: POST_LOGIN_REJECTED,
            payload: null
        }))
    },
    logout: () => dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGOUT,
            payload: null
        })
    },
```

// authReducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    token: "",
    userRole: "",
    isLoading: false,
    loginFailed: false,
    isAuthenticated: false,
}

export function authReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case POST_LOGIN_PENDING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            }
        case POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED:
        return {
            ...state,
            token: action.payload.token,
            userRole: action.payload.userRole,
            loginFailed: false,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            isLoading: false,
        }
        case POST_LOGIN_REJECTED:
            return {
                ...state,
                loginFailed: true,
                isLoading: false,
            }
```

// studentActions.js

```
export const studentActions = {
    getAllStudents: props => dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ALL_STUDENTS_PENDING,
            payload: null,
        })
        axios.get(STUDENTS_ENDPOINT, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${props.token}`
            }   
        })
        .then(res => 
            dispatch({
            type: GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED,
            payload: res.data
        }))
        .catch(err => dispatch({
            type: GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED,
            payload: err
        }))
    },
```

// studentReducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    students: [],
    err: "",
    isLoading: false,
}

export function studentReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_ALL_STUDENTS_PENDING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
        }

        case GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED:
            return {
                ...state,
                students: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
        }

        case GET_ALL_STUDENTS_REJECTED:
            return {
                ...state,
                err: action.payload,
                isLoading: false,
        }
        case DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID_FULFILLED:
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

When a user logs in and the POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED applies. I would expect only the initialstate of the authReducer to be updated, but when inspect with the redux devtools I can see that that the array "studens" which is part of the initialstate of the studentReducer also is updated. From what I understand this should not be possible.

After the user has logged in the students array is filled: (From redux devtools)

```
student: {
   students: [] => {....some stuff}
   isLoading: true => false
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete code of studentReducer.js including the studentReducer function

Comment: Check value of `POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED` with student actions. Make sure they are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading you comments it looks like that **GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED** refers to **POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED** . This must be the reason why your students array is updated. Change

```
 export const   GET_ALL_STUDENTS_PENDING = 'POST_LOGIN_PENDING';
 export const GET_ALL_STUDENTS_REJECTED = 'POST_LOGIN_REJECTED';
 export const GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED = 'POST_LOGIN_FULFILLED';
```

to

```
 export const GET_ALL_STUDENTS_PENDING = 'GET_ALL_STUDENTS_PENDING ';
 export const GET_ALL_STUDENTS_REJECTED = 'GET_ALL_STUDENTS_REJECTED ';
 export const GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED = 'GET_ALL_STUDENTS_FULFILLED ';
```

Action types should be unique or else it might get triggered by some other action